# curl vs libcurl version

Tags: version, libcurl

cURL project has different versions for curl and libcurl. As an example, if you download 8.2.1, the build will produce libcurl.so.4.8.0

Is there any mapping where I can match a libcurl.so with the corresponding curl version?

I have read the Release Table https://curl.se/docs/releases.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SO library version is defined in [/lib/CMakeLists.txt:82-83](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/d6d458b1cf1bf2c34cd39cff9ef9a0e0070b992c/lib/CMakeLists.txt#L82-L83)

```cmake
  math(EXPR CMAKESONAME "${VERSIONCHANGE} - ${VERSIONDEL}")      # 4
  set(CMAKEVERSION "${CMAKESONAME}.${VERSIONDEL}.${VERSIONADD}") # 4.8.0
```

It's assigned to the target shared library in [/lib/CMakeLists.txt:210-211](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/d6d458b1cf1bf2c34cd39cff9ef9a0e0070b992c/lib/CMakeLists.txt#L210-L211)

```clang
    set_target_properties(${LIB_SHARED} PROPERTIES
      VERSION ${CMAKEVERSION} SOVERSION ${CMAKESONAME})
```

The used values are defined in [/lib/Makefile.soname:25-27](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/d6d458b1cf1bf2c34cd39cff9ef9a0e0070b992c/lib/Makefile.soname#L25-L27)

```make
VERSIONCHANGE=12
VERSIONADD=0
VERSIONDEL=8
```

4.8.0 is the ABI version, not the curl version. Any application that requires libcurl 4.8.0 or newer will work with libcurl.so.4.8.0 of curl 8.2.1. You should not change 4.8.0 to 8.2.1.